# Processing 3.2.2 trig functions not returning right results

Tags: processing, trigonometry

I am trying to use the trig functions in processing 3.2.2 on a mac. I have found that when I use the tangent function concurrently with the degrees function, the answer it returns appears to be wrong. Here is the line of code that is causing the issue:

```java
System.out.println(tan(degrees(13)));
```

I have done the calculation on two separate calculators, and I got `.2308681` both times. However, when I run this line on processing, it returns `0.29583776`. What is causing this difference in answers, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: `degrees` converts radians to degrees. You are assuming it does the reverse. Use `radians`.

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this, where you're confused about something a Processing function is doing, are best answered by looking at [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

The reference for the `degrees()` function (which you can read [here](https://processing.org/reference/degrees_.html)) says:

> Converts a radian measurement to its corresponding value in degrees.

So, the `degrees()` function goes **from radians to degrees**. It looks like you're trying to go from degrees to radians. For that, you want the `radians()` function.

```
println(tan(radians(13)));
```

This prints out `0.23086819` like you were originally expecting.

You might also want to get into the habit of debugging your program. One way to do that is to split lines up into multiple steps, so you can see exactly what's going on. So your original code could be broken up like this:

```
float radianValue = degrees(13);
println("radian value: " + radianValue);
float tanValue = tan(radianValue);
println("tan value:" + tanValue);
```

This would have showed you which step was behaving differently from what you expect (in this case, you would have seen that the `degrees()` function wasn't returning what you thought it would). Then you could consult the Processing reference for more info.